# Selecting data by difference between rows in a Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a question on how I could select data points, within a matrix, for plotting. What I have is a matrix (1504 x 2) where the first column is time and the second is the measurement.

Many of the measurements are very nearly equal to the prior, so I only want to graph those that are at lease 0.1 units from the previous measurement. I know I can use 'diff' to get the difference in measurement but how do I select the rows (from the original data set) that are > or = to 0.1 from the prior measurement?

I have

```
v= dataset;
    v2= v(diff(v)<.1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) of the difference values compared to the threshold:

```
v = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; .5 .56 .57 .7 .9 .87 .6 .4].'; % data
th = .1; % threshold
indKeep = [true; abs(diff(v(:,2)))>=th]; % this assumes the first value is always kept
vPlot = v(indKeep,:); % apply as logical index into the rows of v
```

In the example,

```
v =
   1.000000000000000   0.500000000000000
   2.000000000000000   0.560000000000000
   3.000000000000000   0.570000000000000
   4.000000000000000   0.700000000000000
   5.000000000000000   0.900000000000000
   6.000000000000000   0.870000000000000
   7.000000000000000   0.600000000000000
   8.000000000000000   0.400000000000000

vPlot =
   1.000000000000000   0.500000000000000
   4.000000000000000   0.700000000000000
   5.000000000000000   0.900000000000000
   7.000000000000000   0.600000000000000
   8.000000000000000   0.400000000000000
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Luis!

Comment: @Sabre Glad I could help :-)